# Setting variables in Magento blocks

Tags: magento, block

I have the following code in my template file:

```
<?php foreach($collection as $product): ?>
        <?php Mage::unregister('product'); ?>
        <?php Mage::register('product', $product); ?>
       <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
       <div class="product-view">
            <div class="product-essential">
                <form action="<?php  echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <div class="no-display">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $product->getId() ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-shop">
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <h1><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></h1>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
                        <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <div class="add-to-box">
                                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                                    <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                        <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                            <div class="short-description">
                                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-img-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

In my layout XML I have:

```
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="test" template="path/to/products.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

I know it is called successfully as I've output static content from it. However, it appears as if

```
$product
```

isn't being recognised by the block, even though it is a valid product instance.

The code is lifted straight from default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml where it works fine. All my code does/tries to do is change the product. This is the first time I've worked with blocks and would be grateful for any help/tips/pointers as to where I've gone wrong.

Thanks in advance :-).

**EDIT**

It turns out my understanding of blocks/Magento was incorrect. The answer lies in reading the AlanStorm tutorials.

Comment: You use both `$product` and `$_product` which is confusing, give them meaningful names if they're disparate. Also, what is the point of registering the object at the top of the loop when you don't use it?

Comment: catalog/product_view looks for a $product variable (in getProduct() it searches Mage registry for it). So it is used. And the naming conventions come straight from core Magento code.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, first try replacing all double with single quotes in layout xml.
I hope you just dummy-quoted `template="path/to/products.phtml"` for presentation here and used real Magento path in your code.
Can't tell you more cause i'm also beginner in Magento. Just few useful links:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento
http://inchoo.net/category/ecommerce/magento/

Comment: Replacing the double with single quotes is invalid XML. Yes, I use the correct path in my code. I've perused both sites multiple times for help and so far have not found an answer. I'm going to keep looking though.